# Active navigation bar in php

Tags: php, navigation, nav, navigationbar

I have made a menu bar in a separate file and included it all pages. I am trying to achieve a good active php code to make my navigation bar active when I am on the page even on the dropdown. Most of the time I do get errors using the `$_GET` method. If anyone could help me with a simple active function using php that would be great.

Page: nav.php

```
if ($_GET['table'] != 'users')
{ $page1 = 'none'; } else { $page1 = 'active'; }
if ($_GET['table'] != 'carrier_exceptions')
{ $page2 = 'none'; } else { $page2 = 'active'; }.............

     <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Users">Users</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#Carrier_Exceptions" class="dropbtn">Carrier Exceptions</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#Carrier_Costing">Carrier Costing</a>
                    <a href="#Carrier_Code">Carrier Code</a>
                    <a href="#Carrier_Service_Code">Carrier Service Code</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#Markup_Percent">Markup Percent</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Service_Code">Service Code</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Snap_Activity_Pricing">Snap Activity Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Vat">Vat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Country_Code">Country Code</a></li>

            <li style="float:right"><a href="#Logout">Logout</a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: include_once('yourHeaderFileLocation'); ?

Comment: What you mean with "active php code to make my navigation bar active when I am on the page" ... if you include it, it wil be always there when you're on the page?

Comment: @ka_lin - I've already added it on all of my page. I wanted to achieve a php code that could just activate what page I am in.

Comment: @Nicocaine what does it mean and if their are too many if and else block then use ternary operator